# Testing equality of Annotations with different parameters

Tags: java, annotations, equals

OK, so say I have annotations like the following:

`@AAA(value1 = "x", value2 = "x")  @AAA(value1 = "y", value2 = "x")`

Is there an official method or something that would tell me these two are equal (simply because the Annotation for both is "AAA")? Like, one that ignores the parameters and just tests whether they're the same type of annotation. I mean, worst case scenario I could just convert them both to strings and test everything before the open parenthesis, but that seemed a bit hackish.

Comment: In what context? If you've got two references to `Annotation` objects, you can just call `getClass()`, surely...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, I will try that. I do have two Annotation objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to **annotationType()** and then compare the returned classes.

```
Annotation a, b;
...
if (a.annotationType().equals(b.annotationType())) ...
```